# Adjunct for solution operator of Poisson problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, boundary-value-problem

Consider the Poisson problem with Neumann boundary conditions

$\Delta u = f$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$

$\partial_{\nu}u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$

where $\Omega$ is Lipschitz and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. Now we know that the problem has unique solution $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and that the solution operator is linear and bounded.

We can then interpret the solution operator as a function

$S\colon L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega), \, f \mapsto u$

this is a well defined, bounded and linear map. My question now is: What is the Hilbert adjunct of $S$?

Per definition we have to find $S^\ast$ such that,

$\langle f, \, S^\ast v \rangle = \langle S f, \, v \rangle = \langle u, \, v \rangle$

for every $v \in L^2(\Omega)$. Remarkably I was unable to find anything about that in my literature.

Looking at the weak formulation of the problem, I might have guessed the adjunct is in direct relation to the differential operator, the Laplacian in this case, but I am not sure how, because $v$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$.

A related question would be if we could do something similar for the boundary data. That is having a problem

$\Delta u = 0$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$

$\partial_{\nu}u = g$ on $\partial \Omega$

for $g \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$. Can now say something about the Hilbert adjunct $B^\ast$ of

$B\colon L^2(\partial \Omega) \to L^2(\Omega), \, g \mapsto u$?

Comment: $S$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f, g\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $u = Sf, v = Sg$ (to be understood in the weak sense). Then
\begin{align*} 
\langle Sf, g\rangle & = \int_\Omega ug\, dx = \int_\Omega \nabla v\cdot\nabla u\, dx \\
\langle f, Sg\rangle & = \int_\Omega fv\, dx = \int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla v\, dx.
\end{align*}